# What are the different build-in filters available in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

What are the different build-in **filters** available in Angular.js can anyone explain me with example.

Comment: Angular documentations has list of built in filters- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter if you click on filter name, you can see documentation for that filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check them on angular js documentation....any way here are some links with some examples....Hope these will help you to understand how they works in angular js
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

http://www.programming-free.com/2013/10/exploring-angularjs-built-in-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

here is the list of Angular built-in filters, with proper explanation.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter